# Camel executing flow after exception is thrown

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I have two different routing classes(RouteBuilder). In first RouteBuilder, it picks the files and does some process and send to another route flow which is defined in the second routeBuilder.

Here the trick, I defined all exception strategies in the first RouteBuilder and expecting the second RouteBuilder to inherit it. I don't know whether camel supports this or not. Please let me know if any problem with this

Now the problem what i am facing is, when the exception is throwing inside Second routeBuilder. It is executing the main route flow as well as the exception strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct behaviour, it depends what and how you want to handle in the expection block.

Here it is explained in details http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html